# How to connect JavaFx application to a fingerprint scanner

Tags: java, javafx, fingerprint

I am creating a "Entry gate system" application which generates pass for the visitors which requires their information like name , company for which they work for phone no etc.

I want to add a fingerprint scanner to it so that if someone visits again we can retrieve their data by their fingerprint quickly. 
I searched the internet but didn't find anything good.

And is there any fingerprint simulator to test out my Application.

Comment: Which fingerprint reader are you using? Do you have their API? You should not be searching on how to do it in JavaFX but how to do it in Java. Personally I have done it and it was not different from how anyone else would in Java. Search how ti do it in Java, that's all the other bit to do with JavaFX is just for GUI aesthetics because that's basically what JavaFX is meant for.

Comment: OK thanks, can you recommend me fingerprint readers having API .

Comment: @Joseph site not opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the process is like this:

Is the hardware you need to connect with somekind of industry standard?

If yes, then search the internet see if there is somekind of standard API for interfacing with it from Java.

If not, then find out its specs, write some native code (probably C) and use JNI to interface to that in Java.